# How to get the current datetime in add column script in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I need to add the current datetime to ALTER TABLE ADD Column (not null) script. I tried
following and got below error

alter table table1 add created_by  varchar(20) default  '' not null , create_date datetime default getDate() not null ,
last_updated_by  varchar(20) default '' not null,last_update_date  datetime default getDate() not null

```
Could not execute statement.
ALTER TABLE 'table1' failed. Default cannot be an expression
when adding non-NULL column 'create_date'. Use a default value instead.
Sybase error code=13918
Severity Level=16, State=1, Transaction State=1
Line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use getdate as default if you specify column as null

```
for example:
 alter table test add col3 datetime default getdate() null
```